How do I set the upper and lower 95% confidence interval curves to red when generating Kaplan-Meier survival graphs in MedCalc version 23?
How do I set the upper and lower 95% confidence interval curves to red when generating Kaplan-Meier survival graphs in MedCalc version 23? I can not find and implement this function in the software.

What I have tried: Search the internet and the user manual for details.

So not Excel then?

@DarrenBartrup-Cook Not Excel, I have no permission to add tag.

Spreadsheet is a valid tag, as is Charts. Please share with us any research you have done and what you have tried so far regarding this. Add that info to the question.

The answer is no option for this function in MedCalc version 23 from the official answer.
